# How to update table based on PHP Array

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a simple PHP page with MySQL Backend in which there is one table with the following structure:

pkey
phone
name
used

It contains 55K records, what I want is to display a table with 3000 records and have a button that when clicked it will update the "used" column of those displayed records.

I can retrieve and populate the table and put the values into an array, I just need help in how to update those records.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you returning random or sequential rows? If sequential rows, the only thing the button needs to transmit is the start and end row (which you can code straight into the button's html when rendering the page). However, if you can't trust the user, then instead you can try something like having a table of random alphanumeric tokens and the range of rows associated with it, and embed the token in the  button's submit - when you get the token, set the rows associated with it as 'used'. Something like that might work.

Comment: If it's random you can have the sql ids for the rows saved in hidden field(s) and using that when the button is clicked to find the rows to update with a post.

Comment: @QuentinEngles That's fine if you trust the user or if it doesn't matter whether you trust them or not.

Comment: Right now its sequential rows, but i want to randomize, I just want to know what the sql code would look like.

Comment: @Rayvyn `WHERE pkey IN`. Look up the IN operator

Comment: @Patashu Though IDs are the simpler method and they might be a good place to start I agree they could be insecure. The only compromise I can think of is using only a part of the id with the phone and name. As long as the phone, or name is unique. Then use LIKE on the ID. Random tokens would work, but if it's possible to use the present data that is probably the best way as long as the input is cleaned up or sent through a prepared statement.

Comment: @Quentin To make it secure by default, you have to have server side (table or PHP) session data, like a token which is associated with rows, and when you submit with that token it knows you've used those rows, and that way you can't trick the server. (I don't know any of the practice of it lol, just the theory)

Comment: @Patashu Maybe I put too much faith in prepared statements. :)

Comment: @Quentin Engles The #1 rule about writing websites and webservices is you can't trust anything the user sends to you. Even with as simple to use tools as Google Chrome's 'inspect element' you can arbitrarily edit the HTML, javascript, parameters of a form, etc. before sending.

Comment: @Patashu i get that the SQL query would look like `UPDATE X SET a=b WHERE id IN (a,b,c)` but I don't know how to populate the `IN` operator with my array data...

Comment: I got it, i was thinking of `explode` but what I need is `implode` since I need to transform an array into a sting for my query. I'll try it out and comment.

Comment: HA! found it, it was a combination of  `array_map` and `implode`, the PHP code looks like this: `$ids = array_map(function($row) { return $row[0]; }, $numbers); $output = implode(',', $ids);` and the mySQL code looks like this `UPDATE x SET a=b WHERE id IN $output`. This wokrs nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for me to update the rows previously fetched I needed to extract an identifiable value that was unique to each row, in this case the `pkey` column which is the Primary Key for that table.

In order for me to fetch that value I RTM and found the function [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

The PHP code is:

```
function row ($row) {
    return $row[0];
}
$ids = array_map("row", $numbers);
```

This returned and array with all the `Pkey`'s, next I just needed to turn that array into a string to be inserted in the SQL query, I did so like this:

```
$output = implode(',', $ids);
```

After having my comma separated string I could execute my SQL code:

```
UPDATE table SET x=y WHERE Pkey IN $output
```

That is how I could update multiple rows in a MySQL table with values from a multidimensional array without using a foreach loop.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer if it is the solution! You are encouraged to.